# [JAVA/LWJGL]Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, lwjgl

I don't see the } I'm supposed to add, it gives the error at line 30(where the '{' for the createViewMatrix is). I hope someone knows what's going on here.
I honestly don't think it's a problem with my code.

```
package toolbox;

import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Matrix4f;
import org.lwjgl.util.vector.Vector3f;

import entities.Camera;

public class Maths 
{   
   public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation, float rx, float ry, float rz, float scale)
   {
      Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
      matrix.setIdentity();

      // setting position
      Matrix4f.translate(translation, matrix, matrix);

      // settings rotations
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rx), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), matrix, matrix);
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(ry), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), matrix, matrix);
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rz), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), matrix, matrix);

      // setting scale
      Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale, scale, scale), matrix, matrix);

      return matrix;
   }

   public static Matrix4f createViewMatrix(Camera camera)
   {
      Matrix4f viewMatrix = new Matrix4f();
      viewMatrix.setIdentity();

      // setting rotations
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getPitch()), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getYaw()), new Vector3f(0, 1, 0), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);
      Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(camera.getRoll()), new Vector3f(0, 0, 1), viewMatrix, viewMatrix);

      // setting position
      Vector3f cameraPos = camera.getPosition();
      Vector3f negativeCameraPos = new Vector3f(-cameraPos.x, -cameraPos.y, -cameraPos.z);
      Matrix4f.translate(negativeCameraPos, viewMatrix, viewMatrix);

      return viewMatrix;
   }﻿﻿﻿
}
```

Comment: Delete and rewrite the last two enclosing `}`

Comment: For some reason that actually fixed it. Thanks!